# Illegal Syntax Expecting valid start name character

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

How do I escape the `&` in the app settings? I've tried `\` but didn't work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="preset" value="iPhone & iPod Touch"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The `&` in the preset key value causes error `Illegal Syntax Expecting valid start name character`

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I guessed it might have been &amp; but was difficult to debug as I'm writing a service. If your all confident so am I.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't *escape* it, bur rather *encode* it to `&amp;`:

```
<add key="preset" value="iPhone &amp; iPod Touch"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try &amp;
```

Try the above the string instead of &